# How do 3D glasses work?

Tags: optics, soft-question

I am really curious as how do 3D glasses work. I know that they uses some kind of circular polarizers but how does this actually make the screen jump right out at you?

Comment: From typing "3d" into wikipedia I got [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereoscopy), which is quite elaborate and should answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your brain has mainly 3 tricks for determining how close an object is.

1. Pure picture analysis. This is the part where the brain combines perspective and past experience of how big objects should be, to decide how far away something is. This is the only manner of depth perception you have available to you when watching conventional pictures and movies, and it can be toyed with, as in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNbF006Y5x4) by Richard Wiseman.
2. Comparing the perspective of your two eyes. This is the one that becomes active in 3D movies. The easiest way to understand how it works is to close one eye, and bob your head from side to side, while focusing on a single object (this might make you look like a fool). You can see things appear to move relative to one another, and things that are farther back seems to be more stationary. When you have both eyes open, you don't need the bobbing, as you already have input from two different perspectives, and a brain well versed in interpreting it.
3. Focal strength. The third way your brain percieves distance is it gauges the lenses in your eye. This in turn becomes a measure of how far away an object is. If you close one eye and hold one object quite close to your open eye, and shift focus from that object to the background immediately behindto it, I can almost promise you that your closed eye moves away from your nose. This is because your brain is anticipating that the lesser focus means you're looking at something farther back, and thus moves the other eye to try to focus on that instead (even though it can't see anything).

I have heard that number the reason many people have trouble with headaches etc. after watching 3D-movies, is that because no matter how much the perspective and eye movement tries to fool your brain into thinking that objects are closer and further back, your focal muscles are *always* focused on a single distance some 50-200 feet away (the canvas). This dissonance makes your brain uncomfortable, and it will have a real physiological effect, just as dissonance between what your eyes see and your inner ear balance organ feels makes you nauseous (that's motion sickness).

Answer (score 0):

It's more about how the brain with the eyes construct the image than a physics issue. The movie is projected onto the screen, but it's projected twice at the same time. But both projections are not the same image, but they're spatially separated a certain distance related to the characteristic separation of the eyes in a human (the movies are recorded with two cameras at the same time with this spatial separation).

Later, each eye receives just one projection each due to the 3D glasses (be it linear or circular polarizers) and the brain reconstruct a "3D" image out of it.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the specific question about 3-D movies, I can add this:

As explained above,  the 3-D movies camera makes two simultaneous movies from points of view separated by the normal distance between the eyes. (They're probably recorded side by side on the same film.)

The 3-D projector projects these two images, each through its own polarizer, right on top of each other onto an expensive screen that reflects light without destroying the polarization of the light.  The two images will be in register, except where they differ. The two polarizers have directions of polarization at right angles to each other.

Lastly, the crossed polarizing filters on the two lenses of the dorky glasses ensure that each eye sees only one of the images, the one for that eye.  Then, all the human physiology and brain processing power goes to work to analyze the differences between the images and create the effect of a three-dimensional image.